# Reading bitmaps as matrix (trouble with inconsistency in bitmap)

Tags: python, numpy, bitmap

## What the program does:

Im making a program that reads bitmaps (24bit)
Searches for 0xff or 0x0 in the bitmap string 
fills a matrix which costist of zeros, off the same size as the pictures size
changes the correct matrix value to 1 for the value 0x0.
Then it reads each binary column and creates a string
The string is converted to hex and saved in a document.

The images are just black/white images.

## The issue:

Problem is I got it to work with two different test images i have. 
One is 8x8 and the output grid is as expected.

The other is 17x15 and the output is also as expected.

I made several new images, 11x8px and those come out entirely wrong. Somewhere i have too many characters in the returned bitmap string.

I read the bitmaps ignoring the 54 first characters, then I remove any odd symbols that are thrown in there. Anything that isnt either 0xff or 0x0 is removed.

Yet for the 11x8px i have some remaining symbols.

The problematic image is 11x8px with black pixels around the edge and nothing else.

That should be 88 pixels total and in 24-bit format should contain 264 entries in pairs of 3 for BGR values. After removing the 54 first entries of header and removing odd characters i have 288 entries. 24 characters too many and my code doesnt work due to it..
Examples of inputs loaded as BMP and output grids.
You can see the square grid does not appear correctly while the other ones do.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxCj4.jpg

The string of the square BMP file:

```
"BMV      6   (                                                                         ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ         ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ   ÿÿÿ   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ         ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ         ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ         ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                          "
```

Any idea whats going on? Where are these 24 misplaced symbols and what do they mean?

---

### Code: BmpToCharset

```
import numpy as np
import readBmp as ri

#test strings
str1 = "                   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ      
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                  ÿÿÿ         ÿÿÿÿÿÿ         ÿÿÿ   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ   
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ   ÿÿÿÿÿÿ   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ      ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ"

str2 = "ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ      ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                  
ÿÿÿ         ÿÿÿÿÿÿ         ÿÿÿ   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ   ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ   ÿÿÿÿÿÿ   
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ      ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ"


def bmpToChar(filename,width,height):

#Get string from filename
string = ri.readBmp(filename)

#Amount of HexValues per pixel
hexValues = int(len(string)/(width*height))

if len(string)%(width*height) != 0:
    print("ERROR! Unicode string is wrong lenght.\n Lenght",len(string),"Expected multiples of",width*height,"but got",len(string)%(width*height),"unkown values")

print("------------------------------------------------------")
print("Unicode string lenght:",len(string),"\nImage width:",width,"\nImage height:",height,"\nValues per pixel: ",hexValues)

#x,y position to start at
x = 1
y = 1
#pixel counter
count = 1


#Create array with zeros:
grid = np.zeros((height,width))
print("grid:\n",grid)


#Loop through values of bitmap file
while y <=height:
    while x <=width:
        #Loop for each value in bitmap from 0 to the last hex value
        for i in range(0,hexValues):

            if hex(ord(string[count-1]))=="0xff":
                color = "white"
            else:
                color = "black"

            #Only show x value and skip the rest
            if count%hexValues == 0:
                print("Hex entry nr:",count,hex(ord(string[count-1])),"at x:",x,",","y:",y,":", "color:",color,": pixel nr:",int(count/hexValues))

                #Set correct binary value
                if color == "black":
                    binValue = 1
                else:
                    binValue = 0

                #Change value of grid:
                grid[(height-1)-(y-1),(x-1)] = binValue
                print("New grid:\n",grid)


            #else:
                #print("Hex entry nr:",count,"not divideble by", hexValues)
            count +=1
        x += 1
    x = 1
    y += 1

print("Ended loops at x:",x," y:",y)

#Print final matrix:
print("Final grid:\n",grid)



#Save grid in file
file = open('CharInHex.txt','w')

#File Syntax prefix
file.write("{{")

for j in range(0,width):
    #Reset binString to be empty
    binString = ""
    #Take current column and save it as binColumn
    binColumn = grid[:,j]
    print("\nbinColumn:",j+1,"\n",binColumn)

    #For each binary entry in the binColumn save the entry to binString

    for k in range(0,height):
        #from bottom up height-1-k. From top just k
        binString += str(int(binColumn[height-1-k]))
    print("binString of column:",binString)

    #Save as a hexa value
    hexColumn = hex(int(binString,2))
    print("hex(binString):",hexColumn)

    #Save in file
    file.write(hexColumn)
    if j != (width-1):
        file.write(",")


#File Syntax suffix
file.write("}}")
file.close()

#read file
fr = open('CharInHex.txt','r')
text = fr.read()
print("\n Saved document reads: \n",text)
fr.close()
```

## Reading the file and returning the string used by the above program:

```
#Reads Bitmap from filename and returns the string - first 54 chars.

def readBmp(filename):

#Read file
fr = open(filename+'.bmp','r')
bmpRaw = fr.read()
#Empty Header
fileInfo = ""
#Empty Pixel BGR string
string = ""
bmpRawLen = len(bmpRaw)
oddSymbols = 0


for i in range(0,54):
    fileInfo += bmpRaw[i]
    print("bitmap raw string:",bmpRaw,"\nRaw string 
    lenght",bmpRawLen,"\nFile info:",fileInfo)
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------- 
    ----------------")

print("Displaying header info:")
for j in range(0,54):
    temp = hex(ord(fileInfo[j]))
    intVal = int(ord(fileInfo[j]))
    print("Entry:",j+1,"symbol:","'"+fileInfo[j]+"'","hex:",temp,"numeric value:",intVal)


#Create file without header:
print("\nRemoving header")
for k in range(54,bmpRawLen):
    #Show each added symbol COMMENT OUT
    print("Entry:",k+1,"symbol:","'"+bmpRaw[k]+"'","hex:",hex(ord(bmpRaw[k])),"int:",int(ord(bmpRaw[k])))

    if (int(ord(bmpRaw[k])) == 255):
        string += bmpRaw[k]
    elif (int(ord(bmpRaw[k])) == 0):
        string += bmpRaw[k]
    else:
        print("found odd symbol:","'"+bmpRaw[k]+"'","at entry:",k,"which was 
        not added to string") 
        oddSymbols += 1

print("Done. Removed header and",oddSymbols," odd symbols from rawBmp")
print("\nString without header:\n",string,"\nLenght of string:",len(string))


fr.close()
return string
```

Comment: You need [edit] your question and correct the indentation of your code to make it more readable.

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand. Are you reading Microsoft BMP files or some other format that nobody has heard of? If you are reading normal BMP files, why don't you use a library like most people do? If you are reading some other type of file, you need to supply a specification of how it works please.

Comment: Im reading raw 24-bit bitmap files. 54 Characters of header and then 3 values for each pixel. For an image of 10x10 pixels thats 100 pixels total, 300 values in pairs of 3 (Blue, Green, Red) +54 characters of header info before the pixel string. I need to read the raw file and convert it to a specific string for a project im working on. My problem is I clearly dont uderstand how bitmaps are coded.

I have not found a library that does what i want it to do.
A bitmap is a bitmap? are there other types of bitmaps?